# tsc from node_modules doesn't throw console exception when there are typecheck issues

Tags: typescript, tsc

I added small `typecheck` command to run during my ci in order to ensure that there are no type errors. It uses tsc from node modules i.e.

```
./node_modules/.bin/tsc --noEmit;
```

This runs fine and console logs correct errors however the command itself passes with successful exit code. Ideally I want it to throw an exception and exit with error code.

Is there a flag or some tsconfig option I am missing that allows this?

Comment: My local `tsc` exits with code 2 on compilation failure. Have you checked the exit code when you run it manually outside of CI?

Comment: What kind of CI? What does the whole command in your CI look like?

Comment: @shkaper Github Actions, full command is one mentioned in the question

Comment: @ChrisHeald yep, it's 0 to me locally as well

Comment: Could be some tsc quirk - which version do you use?

Comment: @shkaper one that comes with typescript 3.5.1

Comment: Just tested it with 3.6.2 same result, it shows error, but exits with 0

Comment: Can you run it with npx?

Comment: @Ilja can you recreate a minimal repository with the issue?  For me `tsc  --noEmit;` will return non-zero if there is an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after fiddling with this for a while I figured out an issue, I was calling `./node_modules/.bin/tsc --noEmit;` inside a bash script, so my full setup looked like this

**typecheck.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/sh

./node_modules/.bin/tsc --noEmit;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "typecheck": "typecheck.sh"
  }
}
```

And because it was within that script, it didn't throw an error, after some research I was able to make it throw correctly by altering my script to include `set -e`, so in the end this does the trick

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e

./node_modules/.bin/tsc --noEmit;
```